# Changing username without affecting SSH certificate login

Tags: ssh, vpn, login, user

I have secured my SSH logins with certificate authorisation and I want to change my username, so I did. When I did this, I was denied access.
Is there a way to change username without affecting the SSH login process?

Comment: The question is a general unix question and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Ingo Sorry, I thought it was raspberry pi related as I am using it as a server.

Comment: Hi Leon185, it is not that you would not get an answer, at least in a comment. But it is possible that you get votes to close (you have already 3 of 5 as you can see) due to our policies. In your case it doesn't make a difference if you use a RasPi or any other computer. It is only that you may get quicker better answers at e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check if ssh public key remained in authorized file on new user ~/.ssh directory on target machine
2. put new username in connection string on client side too